# Mac R work with mdbtools works with macport install not home-brew install

Tags: r, macos, mdbtools

I am using R to access a .mdb file.

```
library("Hmisc")

mdb.get("NCSS_Lab_Data_Mart_09142018.mdb", tables=TRUE)
```

Before to use this r code, I need to install home-brew for m1 Mac. Then I installed the mdbtools with: brew install mdbtools.
however, my r doesn't work. with error that :

```
ERROR: sh: mdb-tables: command not found
Fehler in system(paste("mdb-tables -1", file), intern = TRUE) :
```

But I can run mdb-ver in my terminal, which means my mdbtools is successfully installed.

Then I use macport to install the mdbtools. Now everything works fine. the R code works very well.

I am just curious what makes this happen. I want to know Why?
thanks for helping me guys!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and did a workaround with using R from the terminal where it ran ok.

So, from RStudio, returns the same error, but when I do it from the terminal (inside R prompt), works fine.